# Android ROS Message

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unsure where to turn to get help for my question, so I might try my luck here.

I am trying to send a message to a ROS via an Android Application. The message is the string "Hello World".  I tried to do some research and found out that I could use a MessageFactory object but I am unsure what else to do. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am also aware that my node object has not been initialized. I tried doing some research into but haven't got found any information that can help. Any help here also would be appreciated. It is denoted by the comment "known error here".

I will post my code below, along with the packages I included.

```
//packages included

import org.ros.android.BitmapFromCompressedImage;
import org.ros.android.view.RosImageView;
import org.ros.android.view.VirtualJoystickView;
import org.ros.message.MessageFactory;
import org.ros.namespace.NameResolver;
import org.ros.node.Node;
import org.ros.node.NodeConfiguration;
import org.ros.node.NodeMainExecutor;
 

  public void executeCommand(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor){
      Node node;

      try{
          java.net.Socket socket = new java.net.Socket(getMasterUri().getHost(), getMasterUri().getPort());
          java.net.InetAddress local_network_address = socket.getLocalAddress();
          socket.close();
          NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(local_network_address.getHostAddress(), getMasterUri());

          String craneTopic = "/rosout";

          NameResolver appNameSpace = getMasterNameSpace();
          craneTopic = appNameSpace.resolve(craneTopic).toString();

          MessageFactory factory = node.getTopicMessageFactory();// known error here
          std_msgs.String m = factory.newFromType(std_msgs.String._TYPE);

         //nodeMainExecutor.execute(, nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("android/follow_crane")); // unknown what to put here
         
      }catch (IOException e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to execute command",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }  
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283164/android-ros-message/) by [ByteMonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/33680/bytemonster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ByteMonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/33680/bytemonster/) on 2018-02-19**:
About the node object, I had no idea it had to be declared globally. That now is fixed.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-02-19**:
How are you planning to send the message? TCP? I hope not. Is it a websocket?

**Comment by [ByteMonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/33680/bytemonster/) on 2018-02-19**:
hi @arunavanag. I am sending the data via a java socket.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-02-19**:
Great then just configure your java socket to send the wlan id and port = 9090 (rosbridge_websocket default port) and send over to the respective topic.

Here these guys are sending it from Windows Unity to ROS websocket : https://github.com/soliagabriel/holoROS/blob/master/Scripts/Source.cs

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-02-19**:
Have a look at the source script (its in C#). On the other end just launch rosbridge_websocket, and run your node which has the same topic name.

Also you may wanna see the rosbridge messaging protocol: https://github.com/biobotus/rosbridge_suite/blob/master/ROSBRIDGE_PROTOCOL.md

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-02-19**:
Here is rosbridge suite installation if you already dont have it : http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-20**:
@arunavanag: I believe you missed that the OP is trying to use ROS Android. That is a regular client library for ROS 1. No need to run to `rosbridge_suite` immediately.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-02-20**:
My bad, I got it wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-20**:
Suggesting `rosbridge_suite` is not a bad idea necessarily. It's just that the OP appears to want to use ROS Android.

**Comment by [ByteMonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/33680/bytemonster/) on 2018-02-20**:
After looking at the links you gave me @arunavanag, I can't seem to salvage anything off that. I appreciate you trying to help me, however. I think I just need to encapsulate the string in a node and send it over but have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ByteMonster,

To publish messages, you need to create and execute a node. Within the context of the node execution, you can get a publisher and start doing what you want. I'd definitely not go the way of Java sockets in this case; you can use RosJava.

I've created a minimal example app to show the point. You can take a look here: https://github.com/jubeira/ros_android_helloworld, and in particular, at the [main activity](https://github.com/jubeira/ros_android_helloworld/blob/master/ros_hello_world_app/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava/android/ros_hello_world_app/RosHelloWorldApp.java).

Note that the nodes you create should extend `AbstractNodeMain`, and the user code should always be in its `onStart` method. The `ConnectedNode` received by that method will provide you with methods to create publishers and so on.

Hope it helps!

Edit: You can also take a look at the 'official' code samples in Android Core. The most basic example there is this one: https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/kinetic/android_tutorial_pubsub, which is just a bit more advanced than the one I posted above.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-02-21**:
@ByteMonster were you able to solve your problem?

**Comment by [ByteMonster](https://answers.ros.org/users/33680/bytemonster/) on 2018-02-21**:
@juberia I was able to use your example as launching platform to solve my problem. I think it is done, I just need to test it. However I did come across an error in the ROSjava. If can't figure it out I will post another question on the forum